# Run python scripts with sudo motion can't get output

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, raspberry-pi

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo motion'],
        shell = True,
          stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
          stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

out = stdout.decode('utf-8')

print('-----------', out)
```

and i use "python3 sh2.py" running the above script but get the following results

```
[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 4.1.1 Started
[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
-----------
```

How can I get the results

Comment: What do you mean by “can’t get output”? Your script as shown should work, but it’s unclear what output you are expecting. Did you mean to set `stderr` to `suprocess.PIPE`, too?

Comment: I want get ```[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 4.1.1 Started
[22636168:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)``` via stdout but i get empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture stderr via `p.communicate()`, you need to set `stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE` in your `Popen` call (by contrast, it doesn’t seem like you’re using `stdin`):

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo motion'],
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: very thankful !  I do through the use of stderr get the result I want，but the "motion" doesn't seem to be wrong, Why be stderr output rather than stdout?

Comment: And i get number 0 via ```subprocess.call("sudo motion", shell=True)```

Comment: @tomatoKnight “stderr” doesn’t imply that the messages are *errors*. Stderr is used for *diagnostics*, so any kind of informational message goes there as well.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `motion` starts as a daemon, running in the background.

Depending on what are doing, you probably want configure it to run your script when some event occurs, using one of the `on_` configuration settings (`on_event_start`, `on_picture_save`, etc).